# Angular filter in dropdown - assign empty value to "All" selection

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am filtering angular list using dropdown with filter attached:

```
<div class="filter-project-type">
    <select name="project-filter" id="project-filter" ng-model="projectFilter" ng-options="project for project in projectName">
      <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
  <ul class="list" ng-show="showList">
    <task-list-element data='task' ng-repeat='task in tasksList | filter: projectFilter' ></task-list-element>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the controller code

```
$scope.projectName = [];

$scope.showList = false;

$rootScope.tasksList = {};
retrieveTasksFactory.getTasksList()
.then(function (tasks) {
    var i;

    $rootScope.tasksList = tasks;
    if (tasks.length > 0) $scope.showList = true;

    // I am filling project's filter with values
    for (i = 0; i < $rootScope.tasksList.length; i++) {
        var temp = $rootScope.tasksList[i].project;
        if ($scope.projectName.indexOf(temp) == -1) {
            $scope.projectName.push(temp);
        }
     }
}, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
})
```

The values for `projectFilter` are retrieved from the populated `tasksList` and they work. However, I would like to add one more value to the dropdown filter named `All` that would reset the filter so that all elements in `tasksList` are visible.
I tried to solve this by adding default option value for `All`, but it deos not work since once you change the value of dropdown, the `All` value disappears. Has anybody came up with solution for this problem. Adding the `''` to projectName array also does not work, since it gives a blank option value in the dropdown menu.

Regards

Comment: Please post you controller code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add 'All' to your `projectName` list. Then write a filter function to filter `tasksList`. Like this:
HTML:

```
<div class="filter-project-type">
    <select name="project-filter" id="project-filter" ng-model="projectFilter" ng-options="project for project in projectName">
    </select>
</div>
<div>
  <ul class="list" ng-show="showList">
    <task-list-element data='task' ng-repeat='task in tasksList | filter: filterTaskList' ></task-list-element>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.projectName = ['All'];
$scope.showList = false;
$scope.projectFilter = "All";
$rootScope.tasksList = {};

retrieveTasksFactory.getTasksList()
.then(function (tasks) {
    var i;

    $rootScope.tasksList = tasks;
    if (tasks.length > 0) $scope.showList = true;

    // I am filling project's filter with values
    for (i = 0; i < $rootScope.tasksList.length; i++) {
        var temp = $rootScope.tasksList[i].project;
        if ($scope.projectName.indexOf(temp) == -1) {
            $scope.projectName.push(temp);
        }
     }
}, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});

$scope.filterTaskList = function(value, index, array) {
    if($scope.projectFilter == "All") {
        return true;
    } else if(value.project.indexOf($scope.projectFilter) != -1){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I haven't executed this but i think it will work. Hope this helps.